# Prove or disprove one-to-one injective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How does one prove or disprove the following?
$A=\{ 1/2^1, 1/2^2, 1/2^3, 1/2^4... \} = \{1/2^n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$
Prove or disprove that there exists a one-to-one injection between A and $\mathbb{N}$ in which $1 \in N$ is paired with $1/4 \in A$.

Regards

Comment: You might want to google the definition of "invective."  I think you mean "injective."  But I kind of like the image (and domain!) of a mathematically invective map....

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo, I did mean injective. I'm also translating the mathematical terms to English. But how about a way to prove or disprove the existence of such an injective.

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you know the answer without the extra condition on where $1$ is mapped?

Comment: @eventhorizon02, even native English speakers mix up words from time to time.  There's even a word for it:  malapropism.  As for your question, it would help if you could describe (preferably in the post itself, not just in comments) what you've tried and where you're stuck.  People can give better, more helpful answers if they can see where you're coming from.

Comment: Thanks, obviously if I could find such a invective that would be a proof. I found many different ones but not one where 1 is mapped to 1/4. The fact that I could not think of such an invjective does not mean that there isn't one. So if anybody can think of one then that's a proof or is there a way to prove that such an invjective where 1 is mapped to 1/4 is not possible.

Comment: Given one injective map, maybe you can change it in a way so it does what you want it to do? (Maybe you can redefine it at $1$ and some other number?)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out, very easy.
$1/2$ is mapped to $2$, $1/4$ is mapped to $1$ as required and after that $1/2^n$ is mapped to $n$ for $n> 2$.